# Replace "dir/23-example-example/" to "dir/index.php?id=23"

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to do this?

"example.com/dir/dir/1-sample-text" - "example.com/dir/dir/index.php?id=1"

"example.com/dir/dir/1-other-sample-text" - "example.com/dir/dir/index.php?id=1"

"example.com/dir/dir/2-sample-text" - "example.com/dir/dir/index.php?id=2"

"example.com/dir/dir/1-sample-text/?page=2" - "example.com/dir/dir/index.php?id=1&page=2"

Comment: it is pretty unclear what you actually want to achieve. could you please provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dir/dir/([1-0]+)\-([^\?]*)(\?page=([0-9]+))?$ /dir/dir/index.php?id=$1$3
```